# Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403

Tags: php

**Hello im right now working on my first website and get this error code while login in with steam:**

*Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=apikey&steamids=steamid): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in /home/u444882409/public_html/steamauth/userInfo.php on line 4*

**Any suggestions? The file itself looks like this:**

```
<?php
    include("steamauth/settings.php");
    if (empty($_SESSION['steam_uptodate']) or $_SESSION['steam_uptodate'] == false or empty($_SESSION['steam_personaname'])) {
        $url = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$steamauth['apikey']."&steamids=".$_SESSION['steamid']); 
        $content = json_decode($url, true);
        $_SESSION['steam_steamid'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['steamid'];
        $_SESSION['steam_communityvisibilitystate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['communityvisibilitystate'];
        $_SESSION['steam_profilestate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['profilestate'];
        $_SESSION['steam_personaname'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
        $_SESSION['steam_lastlogoff'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['lastlogoff'];
        $_SESSION['steam_profileurl'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['profileurl'];
        $_SESSION['steam_avatar'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatar'];
        $_SESSION['steam_avatarmedium'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatarmedium'];
        $_SESSION['steam_avatarfull'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatarfull'];
        $_SESSION['steam_personastate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['personastate'];
        if (isset($content['response']['players'][0]['realname'])) { 
               $_SESSION['steam_realname'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['realname'];
           } else {
               $_SESSION['steam_realname'] = "Real name not given";
        }
        $_SESSION['steam_primaryclanid'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['primaryclanid'];
        $_SESSION['steam_timecreated'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['timecreated'];
        $_SESSION['steam_uptodate'] = true;
    }

    $steamprofile['steamid'] = $_SESSION['steam_steamid'];
    $steamprofile['communityvisibilitystate'] = $_SESSION['steam_communityvisibilitystate'];
    $steamprofile['profilestate'] = $_SESSION['steam_profilestate'];
    $steamprofile['personaname'] = $_SESSION['steam_personaname'];
    $steamprofile['lastlogoff'] = $_SESSION['steam_lastlogoff'];
    $steamprofile['profileurl'] = $_SESSION['steam_profileurl'];
    $steamprofile['avatar'] = $_SESSION['steam_avatar'];
    $steamprofile['avatarmedium'] = $_SESSION['steam_avatarmedium'];
    $steamprofile['avatarfull'] = $_SESSION['steam_avatarfull'];
    $steamprofile['personastate'] = $_SESSION['steam_personastate'];
    $steamprofile['realname'] = $_SESSION['steam_realname'];
    $steamprofile['primaryclanid'] = $_SESSION['steam_primaryclanid'];
    $steamprofile['timecreated'] = $_SESSION['steam_timecreated'];
?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify you replaced your actual API key with `apikey` - as in `key=apikey` - so you could post here, right? If not, you probably just need an API key from Steam.

Comment: 403 - access denied. You try to access something that you have no permission to access.

Comment: Could be just some kind of ban (IP, key) if you in some way broke rules/agreements.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some tests with my apikey and userId gave by documentation (https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29) and it's work correctly.

I think you don't have the rigth apiKey or once of your conditions is wrong.

Did you check all 2 things ?

Comment: I think key is right otherwise it would be 401  resp code

Comment: I will test change the apikey, and for the second its not my own written code for UserID so i dont know what it could be more.

Comment: I've tried with a wrong apiKey and it was a 403 http response.
Just check you've got the rigth key here : http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey and be sure your `$steamauth['apikey']` and `$_SESSION['steamid']` are correct.